# How to validate a form field in jQuery based on email address domain / TLD? (.com, .net, .edu?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

What would be the best method using jQuery to validate a field to ensure it ends in a specific TLD?  Say I want it to only validate the email field if it ends in **.edu**?

**edit:  just realized jQuery has it's own built-in validation, and not sure if I even need the [bassistance plugin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/&ei=pZILT6OuNKbhiALe2o2lBA&usg=AFQjCNEyR03pvKUL0z8Dng87EJUdJOVIeQ&sig2=QOgCnE0S303NyWpBeg1m7g)?

Comment: **quote:** _"just realized jQuery has it's own built-in validation..."_ You are mistaken.  You would use the above mentioned plugin.

Comment: You may have been reading http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation  which is actually all about the plugin you referenced (note the "Plugins" in the name).

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with that particular plugin, but the it looks like you should be able to extend it with syntax like the following:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("emailOrg", function(email_org, element) {
    email_org = email_org.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+org$/i.test(email_org);
}, "Please specify a valid .org email");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      emailOrg: true
    }
  }
});
```

That example would validate all emails that end in org and no others.

Comment: @BartekR I had no idea you could use 'accept' for things other than file extensions. Makes a lot of sense.